# MySQL Syntax Error on update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have the current code,

```
UPDATE i
SET LeadInventor = 
    CASE 
        WHEN gs.FirstInventorName IS NULL THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
    END
FROM patentdb.Inventor i
    LEFT JOIN patentdb.generalsource gs
    ON i.InventorFirst + ' ' + i.InventorLast = gs.FirstInventorName
```

and I dont understand why it throws the following error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM patentdb.Inventor i     LEFT JOIN patentdb.generalsource gs     ON i.Invent' at line 7
```

The FROM statement is what MYSQL is underlining

Answer (score 1):

This is because the FROM clause isn't valid in a MySQL UPDATE statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

You may have better luck with this:

```
UPDATE Inventor i, generalsource gs
SET i.LeadInventor = CASE
  WHEN gs.FirstInventorName IS NULL THEN 'No'
  ELSE 'Yes'
END
WHERE i.InventorFirst + ' ' + i.InventorLast = gs.FirstInventorName
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect. Have a look at this query:

```
UPDATE patentdb.Inventor i
  LEFT JOIN patentdb.generalsource gs
  ON CONCAT(i.InventorFirst, ' ', i.InventorLast) = gs.FirstInventorName
SET LeadInventor = 
  CASE WHEN gs.FirstInventorName IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
```

In addition, I want to say that in MySQL it is better to use CONCAT function to make new string.